# Laravel Elixir 6 getting exception on "gulp watch"

Tags: javascript, laravel, compilation, gulp, laravel-elixir

When I try to run `gulp watch`, I'm getting this error:

```
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'XXXX\public\build\css\client-18724fe72d.css'
    at Error (native)
```

I tried to leave the `client.scss` file empty, and the error disappeared. I found out that the errors sometimes is appearing when I have these lines in my `client.scss`:

```
// Pages
@import 'pages/client/auth';
@import 'pages/client/normals';
@import 'pages/client/orders';
```

I've already checked each one of them, and there's nothing wrong with the syntax or something like that. Even more, when I run `gulp`, it works without any errors.

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(mix => {
    mix
        .sass('app.scss')
        .sass('client.scss', 'public/css/client.css')
        .sass('panel.scss', 'public/css/panel.css')
        .copy('resources/assets/fonts', 'public/build/fonts')
        .copy('resources/assets/images', 'public/build/images')
        .webpack('app.js')
        .webpack('panel.js')
        .version(['css/app.css', 'css/client.css', 'css/panel.css', 'js/app.js', 'js/panel.js'])
});
```

This is the file structure:

[image: Structure]

Is there something that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you can put where your files are located?, I had the same problem yesterday and I realized that the path of my file was wrong

Comment: @OrlandoCharles, Updated. anyways, I don't think that the path is wrong, because it's compiling those files when I run `gulp`.

Comment: "you all should use only one mix.webpack() until we push a commit to fix a couple things for that." - https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/626#issuecomment-252322287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in my `gulpfile.js`, I copied files/folders to `/build` folder which is probably a problem on Laravel Elixir 6, and when I think about it now, it's sounds a bad approach too.

So what I did to fix the issue was:

- removing these lines from `gulpfile.js`:

  ```
  .copy('resources/assets/fonts', 'public/build/fonts')
  .copy('resources/assets/images', 'public/build/images')
  ```
- placing the `fonts` and `images` folders into the `storage/app/public`
- running `php artisan storage:link` [(storage:link artisan command)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure#the-storage-directory)
- changing the paths in the assets files to the new directory
- running `gulp`

And it fixed my problem. Now I can do `gulp watch` again.

Credit to [ejdelmonico on laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/elixir-6-getting-exception-on-gulp-watch#reply-193110).

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my two cents in here. I had the same issue and it went away as soon as I stopped using the starting / relative path option, and used full relative paths (relative to /resources) instead.

So instead of:

```
mix.styles([
    'vendors/jquery-steps/demo/css/jquery.steps.css',
    'vendors/pace/pace-minimal.css',
    'vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    '../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css',
], 'public/css/vendors.css', 'public');
```

This worked, and `gulp watch` ran again:

```
mix.styles([
    '../../../public/vendors/jquery-steps/demo/css/jquery.steps.css',
    '../../../public/vendors/pace/pace-minimal.css',
    '../../../public/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    '../../../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css',
], 'public/css/vendors.css');
```

It's not pretty, but it works.