# Laravel Elixir - gulp watch automatically tries production and throws an error

Tags: laravel-5, gulp, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

I have a project that I got from my friends, and I setup the environment.

Now when I try `gulp` it works and compiles perfectly. However, if I try to run `gulp watch` it throws error:

```
internal/streams/legacy.js:59
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vagrant/Code/proj/public/
build/js/all-86db1d88de.js'
```

As far as I understand, it is trying to force production or minifying, whereas running `gulp` doesn't so it works.

What am I doing wrong with the `gulp watch`?

Everyone else except me can use `gulp watch`. Our gulp versions are same - 3.9.1, but node versions are different, their one is 6.5.0, my one is 7.10.1

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(mix => {

    mix.sass([
        'app.scss'
    ], 'resources/assets/css/app.css')

    mix.styles([
        'resources/assets/css/custom.css',
        'resources/assets/css/app.css',
        'node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css',
    ],'public/css/all.css','./')

    mix.webpack('app.js','resources/assets/js/webpack-app.js')


    mix.scripts([
        'resources/assets/js/webpack-app.js',
        'node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js',
        'node_modules/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.min.js',
        'resources/assets/js/parsley-custom.js',
        'resources/assets/js/custom.js',
    ],'public/js/all.js','./')

    mix.version(['css/all.css', 'js/all.js'])

    mix.copy('resources/assets/js/libs/salvattore.min.js', 'public/js/libs');

    mix.copy('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/build/fonts');
});
```

Comment: Need to see your gulpfile.

Comment: @Mark I added it. `gulp watch` works for everyone except me. only `gulp` works for me as I said

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465922/4881811)